# New line character not shown on terminal with mpirun

Tags: c, mpi

As it is my first time asking a question here (and as a non-fluent english speaker), I would be thankful if you were to tell me if I  did something wrong with the way I've written my issue.

When I use mpirun, the newline character (\n) is not printed on terminal, no matter the way I use it (it works when I don't use mpirun though). It seems to be replace by a space character (ASCII 32).

Maybe this will help everyone to identify the issue if you did not yet :

```
printf("tried newline\nend of text");
```

will print

```
tried newline end of text
```

The same thing will be printed if I use the following functions :

```
puts("tried newline\nend of text");

fprintf(stdout, "tried newline\nend of text");

printf("tried newline");
putchar(10);
printf("end of text");

char[]n = "tried newline\nend of text";
printf("%s", n);
```

Of course, before using them I wrote this in order to have the lines written a single time for each one :

```
int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
if(!rank) //with brackets when need
```

This only apply on console. If I write

```
fprintf(stderr, "tried newline\nend of text");
```

the new line will be printed on my error file.

Due to some compatibility issues between MPI and Eclipse (my IDE), I had to use cross GCC instead of Linux GCC. I don't think this matters though, since it works fine if I use cross GCC for a non-parallel related program.

Did someone ever face such issue? Is there a way to solve this problem?